# XQUERY for loop and html

Tags: html, xml, xquery, xmlspy

I have the following XQUERY code in XMLSPY which runs fine.

```
xquery version "1.0";

<table border="1">
{
 for $re in distinct-values(reviews/review/reviewer)
 for $r in reviews/review
 where $re=$r/reviewer
 return  <tr> <td>{$r/movie_title}</td> </tr>
}
</table>
```

Now I want to modify it as follows :

```
xquery version "1.0";

<table border="1">
{
 <tr> <td>
 for $re in distinct-values(reviews/review/reviewer)
 for $r in reviews/review
 where $re=$r/reviewer
 return  {$r/movie_title}
 </td> </tr>
}
</table>
```

But it gives syntax error. What the second code should accomplish is that only outer for loop should create new row and new cell and inner loop should only add to that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for $re in distinct-values(reviews/review/reviewer) return <tr>{
    for $r in reviews/review
        where $re=$r/reviewer
            return <td>{$r/movie_title}</td>
}</tr>
```

This **[XMLPLayground session](http://www.xmlplayground.com/93kjy1)** might help you. It does something similar, i.e. iterative table output.

Comment: Modifying your code for what I want brought me closer to this :

`<table border="1">

{
for $re in distinct-values(reviews/review/reviewer) return <tr><td>{
    for $r in reviews/review
        where $re=$r/reviewer
            return ($r/movie_title)
}</td></tr>
}
</table>`

But I want comma between each return statement

Comment: Where should I put the comma ?

Comment: Why would you want a comma between your `td` tags? This would lead to invalid HTML.